# instance clash error when trying to execute a stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have the following PUT method that is used to update an object in my CashList table via .NET Core & Entity Framework.

I had to add a call to a stored procedure that is on my SQL Server database.

It is called if the object being updated has had a change in one of it's properties (`CashCountry`).

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutCashList(string id, CashList cashList)
{
    var newCashCountry = cashList.CashCountry;
    var currentCashObject = await _context.CashList.FindAsync(id);
    var currentCashCountry = currentCashObject.CashCountry;

    if (newCashCountry.Value != currentCashCountry)
    {
        await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("EXEC bank_UpdateCash {0}, {1}", cashList.CashId, cashList.CashCountry);
    }

    _context.Entry(cashList).State = EntityState.Modified;

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return NoContent();
}
```

But whenever I test it, I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'CashList' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'CashId'} is already being tracked.

I'm not sure why because I'm only trying to update one row.

Any clues would be welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Is that all your code? Or it has some stripped parts for brevity?

Comment: Try to add your DbContext as a scoped service dependency in your project?

Comment: @svyatis.lviv Thanks! I have `services.AddDbContext<bank_ProdContext>` in my Startup.cs file and inject it into each controller.  Do I need something else?

Comment: @Eldar Yes sir, I did take out a long `try catch` block that writes to an error log if something happens to be NULL. But nothing was NULL in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is caused by these two lines :

```
var currentCashObject = await _context.CashList.FindAsync(id);
 _context.Entry(cashList).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

I assume that id belongs to `cashList` parameter. So the first line makes the `CashList` object tracked by Entity Framework. So the second line tries to do the same.
You can change the first line to this:

```
var currentCashObject = await _context.CashList.AsNoTracking().FindAsync(id);
```

To tell the Entity Framework not to track the object you get from db.